# Why do the strings output using fprintf end up not being written to the output file if my program is terminated via CTRL-C?

Tags: c, file-io, printf

Why does `fprintf` give different results in the following example programs?

#### Example 1:

```
int main(){
    FILE *f;
    char buf[512];
    char name[128] = {"filename"};

    f = fopen(name, "w");
    fprintf(f, "asdas\n");
    fprintf(f, "asdas\n");
    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

If I terminate this program using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I get an *empty* file named `filename`.

However, using

#### Example 2:

```
int main(){
    FILE *f;
    char buf[512];
    char name[128] = {"wpa_supplicant.conf"};

    f = fopen(name,"w");
    while(1){
        fprintf(f, "asdas\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If I terminate this program using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, I get file named `filename`, and it contains many lines with the string `asdas`.

Why are the strings not written to the file in the first example, but they are written to the file in the second example?

Comment: buffering? the first one doesn't write enough data to overflow the buffer and trigger a flush before you ^C it, while the second one does? try adding a fflush() after the second fprintf and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: @iharob No. There's nothing wrong with `char name[128] = {"filename"};` and is certainly not an array of string literals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the second case, there are enough [`fprintf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html) calls for the internal buffers to be flushed to disk.

With the first program, if you put a [`fflush(f)`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html) before the `while` loop, the strings will be written to the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f = fopen("filename", "w");
    if (!f) {
        perror("Failed to open 'filename' for writing");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(f, "asdas\n");
    fprintf(f, "asdas\n");

    if ( fflush(f) != 0 ) {
        perror("Flushing output failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1){}
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
C:\...\Temp> cl file.c                       
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 18.00.31101 for x64
...
/out:file.exe                                                      

C:\...\Temp> file                            
^C                                                                 
C:\...\Temp> type filename                   
asdas                                                              
asdas
```

Keep in mind:

> Upon successful completion, `fflush()` shall return `0`; otherwise, it shall set the error indicator for the stream, return `EOF`, and set `errno` to indicate the error.

Comment: To the OP: And hence, adding `fflush(f);` after the last `fprintf()` will solve the problem, you could also add `fclose(f);` to realease resources after wrinting to the file. And check the pointer returned from `fopen()` for `NULL`, because in case you for example don't have write permission your program will invoke undefined behavior because of `NULL` pointer dereference.

Comment: So, this is cause data was in buffering and not put in file,
and need to use fflush(f); to put it into files, thanks!

Comment: **And** you need to check the return values from `fflush()` and `fclose()` because there's no guarantee that the buffered data can actually be written.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [the answer by @SinanÜnür](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30240171/100754) this is indeed an issue with the buffering of data in internal buffers. You need to *flush* manually in the first case to get that data actually *written* into the *file*.

However, FWIW, I just want to add here, you see this behavior because of the abnormal termination of the program by a signal (generated by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>).

If your program would have ended [normally](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Normal-Termination.html#Normal-Termination), (*for example, by calling [`exit()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exit.html), after a large-enough but controlled `while()` loop*), then both the cases would have shown the same behavior, as in that scenario, all the open streams would have been flushed automatically.

> The `exit()` function shall then flush all open streams with unwritten buffered data and close all open streams. Finally, the process shall be terminated ...